# Android Studio Missing Keymap - Cannot find keymap "Windows Proper Redo"

Tags: android-studio

I am seeing a warning message in my event log on android studio that says

```
Missing Keymap  
Cannot find keymap "Windows Proper Redo"  
Search for Windows Proper Redo Keymap plugin
```

[image]

I don’t know what to do.
I try to search the error but it doesn't return the result of android studio ide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a JetBrains mod answered this in an Intelij Support Forum [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4406906400914--SOLVED-Cannot-find-keymap-Windows-Proper-Redo-)

Workaround Instructions:

- Navigate to `File | Settings | Plugins` and install `macOS For All` keymap (or any keymap).
- Switch from `Plugins` to `Keymap` settings tab and change it to `macOS For All`.
- Close the IDE and open it again.
- Navigate to `Keymap` in settings and change `keymap` back to the one you want
- Save changes
- Optionally, delete `macOS For All` keymap now that it's no longer needed.

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer to my question. Unfortunately, I no longer use Android Studio anymore, so I'm unable to test the solution provided. 

However, your response seems promising and might help others who encounter a similar issue. I'll mark this as the accepted answer, and if anyone else can verify it or provide additional feedback, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for following up, I appreciate it.